# Should C++ ever be used to emulate sql

Tags: c#, c++, sql, sql-server

Currently there's a sql function that does a bunch of calculations and I'm wondering if the following would be a good replacement.  I'm thinking of building a C# frontend app that calls sql server and pulls the data and dumps it into a datatable.  From there, I will feed the data as a list or vector(rows from sqldataadaptor class) to C++ which will be better for calculations supposedly.  Here are some assumptions.

1.Must be done in C#, only question is whether to introduce C++

2.The Sql function currently does 3 or 4 select statments on the data which have their unique group by (up to 10 parameters)

-So should I give the data from C# to C++ pre-group (or maybe ordered by instead?) and have C++ take care of this by building some kind of treemap or dictionary and iterating through the table.  It's easy to execute a sql statment in C# and have the data all grouped already but that makes C++ job somewhat useless and it might be to granular

3.the calculations in sql that I'm trying to replace are of the following format

```
  select a = exp(sum(log(x))),
     b = exp(sum(log(x))),
     c = exp(sum(log(y))),
     d = exp(sum(log(z))),
     e = exp(sum(log(u)))
  from data_table
  group by e,f,g,h,k
```

nothing too complicated really, very basic math.

-Again,  It's easy to execute this statement in C# and just return grouped elements but that means the sum() and log() would have been done in C# and C++ rendered useless.  But if I have thousands and possibly tens of thousands of rows in my table per iteration and this is run multiple times a day, will C++ have any advantage in terms of the math (my gut tells me not really).

4.the above calculations correspond to 1 "account", there will be hundreds of account and data_table will have thousands if not more rows per account, this will be run maybe every hour 24/7.

The C# rewrite is inevitable but is there really any reason to leverage C++ for speed.  It's mainly for speed and possibly decoupling for future maintenance but overall speed.  If I use C++, would this be the way to go and what data structures would be most appropriate for working with this data and emulating some of its sql functionality.  I basically need group by, then iterate through it very fast.  Are there any alternatives?  Does C++ feel forced and is completely unnecessary.  THanks.

Comment: I would advise to write the code first and optimise only if you find that speed is a concern.  If you do end up needing to preform the calculations outside SQL then consider a dynamic C library and maybe calling its functions from C#.

Comment: Never optimize before you have the core problem solved.

Comment: As long as it's easy to impelement in SQL i would not switch to C. You said you're going to retrieve all the rows to the application, process it and then send it back, what's the current performance of the SQL implementation? You might try to tune this first.

Answer (score 2):

C++ is not going to be enough of a performance increase to warrant the extra complication, especially before you've even solved the problem.  Go with C# first, then see if your needs are already met.
Like ilent2 said in comments, you can always do the core calculations in c++ and call from C# - reusing the bulk of the C# code.

Also, looking at your problem, it looks like 99% of your speed will come from how you implement the solution, not which language you choose.  Go get 'em!

Answer (score 2):

I would be VERY surprised if there is any gain in performing this sort of calculation in C# or C++. The time it takes to transfer the data from the SQL server to the C# or C++ program will far outweigh the speed difference. Bear in mind that the SQL server still uses the same C or C++ library (or at least one very similar to it) that your C++ or C# code would use, so the actual `exp` and `log` calculation itself is going to be very similar in speed. The overhead comes from the parsing of the SQL elements. And I don't believe there is going to be much difference at all.

If you really think this is an issue (I don't, but then I'm not responsible for the work you are doing...), I would suggest you try to construct a test-case, with some tables with realistic values and realistic sizes (and perhaps a bit larger), and then compare the speed of calculating the values and just fetching the values directly (in pure SQL code - I presume there is a SQL command-line tool that you can use, or some web-interface or something to allow you to perform the calculations). Perhaps returning just the `sum` of the values as well.

Edit: I wrote some bits of PHP (because I pretty much already have a PHP + MySQL environment installed on my machine). [And no, those are NOT my username/password combinatin - I'm not going to post that on a public server like that!]

```
<?php

$dbconnect = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password");
if (!$dbconnect)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("test", $dbconnect) 
    or die ("Couldn't connect to database: " . mysql_error() );

echo "Argv[1]=" . $argv[1] . "\n";


if ($argv[1] == "Create")
{
    $rm = getrandmax();
    for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++)
    {
        $a = rand() / $rm;
        $b = rand() / $rm;
        $c = rand() / $rm;
        $d = rand() / $rm;
        $e = rand() / $rm;
        $f = rand() / $rm;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO test1 (id, a, b, c, d, e, f) VALUES (" 
            . $i . 
            ", " .  $a . ", " . $b . ", " . $c . ", " . $d . ", " . $e
            . ", " . $f . ");";
        if (mysql_query($sql, $dbconnect) === false)
        {
            die("Could not add element " . mysql_error());
        }
    }
}

if ($argv[1] == "ExpSumLog")
{
    $sql = "SELECT exp(sum(log(a))) AS a1,
                 exp(sum(log(b))) AS b1,
                 exp(sum(log(c))) AS c1,
                 exp(sum(log(d))) AS d1,
                 exp(sum(log(e))) AS e1
          FROM test1
          GROUP BY e,f,id";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $dbconnect) or die("Failed " . mysql_error());
    $count = 0;
    $sum = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $count++;
        $sum += $row['a1'];
    }

    echo "Sum=" . $sum . ", count=" . $count . "\n";
}


if ($argv[1] == "Sum")
{
    $sum = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT sum(a) AS a1,
                 sum(b) AS b1,
                 sum(c) AS c1,
                 sum(d) AS d1,
                 sum(e) AS e1
          FROM test1
          GROUP BY e,f,id";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $dbconnect) or die("Failed " . mysql_error());
    $count = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $count++;
        $sum += $row['a1'];
    }

    echo "Sum=" . $sum . ", count=" . $count . "\n";
}

if ($argv[1] == "List")
{
    $sum = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM test1;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $dbconnect) or die("Failed " . mysql_error());
    $count = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $count++;
        $sum += $row['a'];
    }

    echo "Sum=" . $sum . ", count=" . $count . "\n";
}

if ($argv[1] == "SumA")
{
    $sum = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT sum(a) FROM test1;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $dbconnect) or die("Failed " . mysql_error());
    $count = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $count++;
        $sum += $row['sum(a)'];
    }

    echo "Sum=" . $sum . ", count=" . $count . "\n";
}

if ($argv[1] == "ExpSumLogA")
{
    $sum = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT sum(exp(log(a))) AS a1 FROM test1;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $dbconnect) or die("Failed " . mysql_error());
    $count = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $count++;
        $sum += $row['a1'];
    }
    echo "Sum=" . $sum . ", count=" . $count . "\n";
}   
?>
```

Create takes about 55 minutes... Fortunately, the other steps are much faster.

```
Argv[1]=ExpSumLog
Sum=50017.011061374, count=100000

real    0m1.102s
user    0m0.289s
sys 0m0.066s
Argv[1]=Sum
Sum=50017.011061374, count=100000

real    0m1.004s
user    0m0.278s
sys 0m0.055s
Argv[1]=List
Sum=50017.011061374, count=100000

real    0m0.993s
user    0m0.322s
sys 0m0.060s
Argv[1]=SumA
Sum=50017.011061374, count=1

real    0m0.068s
user    0m0.019s
sys 0m0.012s
Argv[1]=ExpSumLogA
Sum=50017.011061374, count=1

real    0m0.095s
user    0m0.024s
sys 0m0.017s
```

As you can see, the time it takes to perform the actual calculations is much less than it takes to copy all the data. And the difference between calculating the data as sum(exp(log(a))) and sum(a) is marginally different (but consistently different - every run is about 20-30 ms slower for the ExpSumLogA and SumA).

To prove that it's the data transfer that is the major point, I added these four variants:

```
if ($argv[1] == "SortedA")
{

    $sum = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT a AS a1 FROM test1 ORDER BY a;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $dbconnect) or die("Failed " . mysql_error());
    $count = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $count++;
        $sum += $row['a1'];
    }
    echo "Sum=" . $sum . ", count=" . $count . "\n";
}

if ($argv[1] == "SortedExpLogA")
{

    $sum = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT exp(log(a)) AS a1 FROM test1 ORDER BY a;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $dbconnect) or die("Failed " . mysql_error());
    $count = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $count++;
        $sum += $row['a1'];
    }
    echo "Sum=" . $sum . ", count=" . $count . "\n";
}

if ($argv[1] == "UnsortedA")
{

    $sum = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT a AS a1 FROM test1;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $dbconnect) or die("Failed " . mysql_error());
    $count = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $count++;
        $sum += $row['a1'];
    }
    echo "Sum=" . $sum . ", count=" . $count . "\n";
}

if ($argv[1] == "UnsortedExpLogA")
{

    $sum = 0;
    $sql = "SELECT exp(log(a)) AS a1 FROM test1;";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $dbconnect) or die("Failed " . mysql_error());
    $count = 0;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $count++;
        $sum += $row['a1'];
    }
    echo "Sum=" . $sum . ", count=" . $count . "\n";
}
```

Clearly, these variants would run quicker than exporting ALL the data, but slower than the one "return just one value", and it does.

```
Argv[1]=SortedA
Sum=50017.011061375, count=100000

real    0m0.375s
user    0m0.194s
sys 0m0.027s
Argv[1]=SortedExpLogA
Sum=50017.011061375, count=100000

real    0m0.394s
user    0m0.202s
sys 0m0.023s

Argv[1]=UnsortedA
Sum=50017.011061374, count=100000

real    0m0.353s
user    0m0.206s
sys 0m0.018s
Argv[1]=UnsortedExpLogA
Sum=50017.011061374, count=100000

real    0m0.383s
user    0m0.223s
sys 0m0.025s
```

As you can see, the time it takes is a little longer for the Sorted than the Unsorted (expected, if you have to sort 100K items, it will add some time), and the ExpLog variant is a little slower than the "just return A" variant. It is fairly consistent like this.

Comment: @LukeMakk: Added some benchmarks. Although they are PHP, the main time is in the MYSQL and the PHP Internal components are written in C anyway.